# Type '{ children: string; class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I'm using React.js and i need to have a class instead of a className in my tsx file, but i get the following message:

> Type '{ children: string; class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'.
> Property 'class' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'. Did you mean 'className'?ts(2322).

I know that the class keyword is a reserved word in JavaScript,and it cannot be used in a jsx file, but i also read that this problem can be solved by allowing it in tsconfig.json file.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

tnx alot for help

I tried to convert the tsx file into a HTML file but it didn´t work

Comment: "*I need to have a class instead of a className in my tsx file*" - Please [edit] the question and explain why you think you need it. Also please explain what problems you run into if you do not have it, and what (other) workarounds you have considered or tried.